# Java regex matching with or clause

Tags: java, regex, string

I've got the following code

```
String valuepairName = "sc_mpl_MAX_AUD_TIME_To_20_Val.$$DATE_TO_LOAD";
boolean result = valuepairName.matches("sc_mpl_MAX_AUD_TIME_To_(20|32|82)_Val.$$DATE_TO_LOAD");
```

The result evaluates to false, but I cannot see the mistake.
This must be very trivial, hence it's driving me crazy :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape each `$` individually (or use `pattern.quote`) (`$` is a *special character* in regex). Use

`boolean result = valuepairName.matches("sc_mpl_MAX_AUD_TIME_To_(20|32|82)_Val.\\$\\$DATE_TO_LOAD");`

Comment: This worked. Didn't think of escaping those dollar signs. Many thanks! :)

Comment: @4Kings - As mentioned by LukStorms, you might want to escape the `.` as well